# WebStorm: Hide html selector toolbar

Tags: ide, webstorm

In WebStorm I want to hide the toolbar that appears on html files at the top.  It shows the html selectors and ids drill down.  I've circled it in the below picture...

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to File -> Settings or press Ctr+Alt+S on windows. Then go to Editor-> General -> Appearance.
Then on the right side of the panel uncheck "Show HTML breadcrumbs(...)" line. Then restart the IDE to take effect.

Comment: No need for IDE restart -- closing and re-opening that file is enough.